# Motorola Atrix 4g force close error

Tags: force-close, motorola-atrix-4g

I am using Motorola Atrix 4g and it's Android 2.3.6 . It worked like a boss for almost 6/7 months. Recently it started showing Force close com.motorola.service.main and restart the phone, then again force close and restart. After restarting almost 10 times it showed the screen. Then I factory reset the set, thought it will solve the problem.

But after resetting the phone it still gives error "com.motorola.service.main has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again" and then force close, but it doesn't restart now. So I can still use the phone. And I live in Bangladesh, so there is no servicing center available for this.

Anyone faced this before? or does anyone have any clue how to fix it?

Comment: didn't anyone face it before? what should I do? and it's not rooted device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the Force Close problem the error was "The process com.motorola.service.main has stopped unexpectedly please try again". Motorola support couldn't solve it so they had me send it for repair. Sent it to them 2X. When i got it back the 3rd time still had the problem so Motorola provided a replacement phone. When i received the replacement the problem occurred again. This only left 2 possibilities, sim card (unlikely) and MotoBlur. I created a new MotoBlur account instead of using my existing one. PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: Solved mine too, thanks a lot. Motorola should give a better support :(